# Согласование существительного и глагола

Tags: согласование, приложение

Можно ли так написать?

> Здесь жила его кумир - Одри Хепберн.

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адвокат Иванова выиграла, врач Смирнова посетила  — здесь рядом стоят слова, которые сочетаются между собой.

А вот в приведенном примере **такой сочетаемости нет**, а это стилистическая (не грамматическая) погрешность.

Лучше так: ***Здесь жила Одри Хепберн — его кумир**.*

Но это надо смотреть по тексту.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это корректно. Правило гласит:

> Существительные мужского рода, обозначающие лиц мужского и женского
> пола типа врач, инженер, технолог, банкир, ассистент, менеджер,
> коммерсант, как правило, согласуются с прилагательными в форме
> мужского рода (т.е. по окончанию), а с глаголами – в форме мужского
> или женского рода в зависимости от принадлежности лица к мужскому или
> женскому полу (т.е. по значению). Например: Опытный адвокат Иванова
> выиграла процесс. - Опытный адвокат Иванов выиграл процесс; Участковый
> врач Смирнова посетила больного. - Участковый врач Смирнов посетил
> больного.

Comment: В этом правиле рассматриваются необособленные приложение (кстати, желательно дать ссылку), а в примере приложение, обособленное тире. Это разная грамматика,  поэтому и правило может  быть другое.